# regarding about export of neptune data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-neptune

I am trying to export Neptune RDF data using the following tools.

amazon-neptune-tools/neptune-export at master · awslabs/amazon-neptune-tools 
https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-neptune-tools/tree/master/neptune-export

But, Error occurs.

> Error

```
[ec2-user@bastin neptune-export]$ sh ./bin/neptune-export.sh export-rdf -e neptestdb-cluster.cluster-xxxxxx.ap-northeast-1.neptune.amazonaws.com -d /home/ec2-user/output
Creating statement files

Completed export-rdf in 1 seconds
An error occurred while exporting from Neptune:
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.amazonaws.services.neptune.rdf.NeptuneSparqlClient.executeQuery(NeptuneSparqlClient.java:166)
    at com.amazonaws.services.neptune.rdf.io.ExportRdfGraphJob.execute(ExportRdfGraphJob.java:31)
    at com.amazonaws.services.neptune.ExportRdfGraph.run(ExportRdfGraph.java:55)
    at com.amazonaws.services.neptune.NeptuneExportCli.main(NeptuneExportCli.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.amazonaws.services.neptune.rdf.io.EnhancedTurtleWriter.handleStatement(EnhancedTurtleWriter.java:42)
    at com.amazonaws.services.neptune.rdf.NeptuneSparqlClient$2.handleSolution(NeptuneSparqlClient.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.resultio.binary.BinaryQueryResultParser.parse(BinaryQueryResultParser.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.resultio.AbstractTupleQueryResultParser.parseQueryResult(AbstractTupleQueryResultParser.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.http.client.SPARQLProtocolSession.getTupleQueryResult(SPARQLProtocolSession.java:693)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.http.client.SPARQLProtocolSession.sendTupleQuery(SPARQLProtocolSession.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.sparql.query.SPARQLTupleQuery.evaluate(SPARQLTupleQuery.java:55)
    at com.amazonaws.services.neptune.rdf.NeptuneSparqlClient.executeQuery(NeptuneSparqlClient.java:126)
    ... 3 more
[ec2-user@bastin neptune-export]$
```

The procedure is as follows.

> Command

```
1. download tool

git clone https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-neptune-tools.git

2. install mvn for build

sudo wget http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/dchen/apache-maven/epel-apache-maven.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/epel-apache-maven.repo
sudo sed -i s/\$releasever/6/g /etc/yum.repos.d/epel-apache-maven.repo
sudo yum install -y apache-maven
mvn --version

3. execute build

cd /home/ec2-user/amazon-neptune-tools/neptune-export
mvn clean install

4. exexute neptune-export.sh
cd /home/ec2-user/amazon-neptune-tools/neptune-export
sh ./bin/neptune-export.sh export-rdf -e https://neptestdb-cluster.cluster-xxxxxxx.ap-northeast-1.neptune.amazonaws.com -d /home/ec2-user/output
```

If you have any idea, please contact us.
thank you for your cooperation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. I've identified the problem and will push an update to the repository later today or tomorrow. In the meantime, you can replace [line 42 in EnhancedTutleWriter.java](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-neptune-tools/blob/master/neptune-export/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/neptune/rdf/io/EnhancedTurtleWriter.java#L42) with the following:

```
Resource context = statement.getContext();
if (context != null){
    prefixes.parse(context.stringValue(), this);
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for update!
I used the new repository source and confirmed that the export was successful!!